# TeXstudio does not recognize csvsimple commands

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

My file compiles fine, but TexStudio doesn't recognise commands from the `csvsimple` package. I tried setting the completion file manually under preferences>completion, but the csvsimple.cwl file is not listed there. In `~/.config/texstudio/completion/autogenerated/` there is however a file `csvsimple.cwl` which lists all the commands that aren't being recognised.

How do I make TexStudio recognize these commands?

Information about my setup: I have installed MacTeX and TeXstudio via brew on MacOS.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, for me [all the ``csvsimple`` commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIO8w.png) copied from the ``.cwl`` are recognized. I needed to restart TeXstudio after first using ``csvsimple`` for this to work, but I am assuming you have restarted TeXstudio since the ``cwl`` was first created, right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP did not react to comment for a long time.